# Select artifact on Phonegap/Cordova on Android

Tags: android, cordova

When I click with a full finger (not just a gentle touch) on or around a div or span that is clickable (has a click event attached to it) I get a 'select-box' around the element and the click will not fire.

See http://s15.postimage.org/bifbc0k3f/knop_vol.png for a screenshot

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer in the meanwhile! The trick is to set the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: [color];` to any fully transparent [color], for example `rgba(0,0,0,0);`.

This will hide the tap-highlight box. See http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color for more info.